# animation doesn't run properly

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, callback, android-animation

```
class DialFragment: DialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var image001: ImageView

    private val caller = object: FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback() {
        override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence?) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
            listener.onDialClick(errString.toString(), "2")
            dismiss()
        }
        override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult?) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
            listener.onDialClick("yes","1")
            var avp = image001.drawable as AnimatedVectorDrawable
            avp.start()
            dismiss()

        }

        override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed()
            listener.onDialClick("no","3")
            dismiss()
        }
```

The animation called by `avp.start()` is not beeing shown, the dialog fragment directly dismisses after succesfull authentification. if i omit the `dismiss()`-Call below then it works properly. My question is why is this and how to fix it? And yes, i know FingerprintManager-API is deprecated, i am running this for test purposes.

Comment: Thankyou Tenfour04 for your quick response, it wasnt possible for me to call 'runOnUIThread(300L)' because the function only gets a lambda expression, but i found another way to block the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

`dismiss()` immediately ends the life of your DialogFragment, so it will have no more opportunity to show you any animations in the Fragment. You should dismiss after a delay (however long the animation is).

```
    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult?) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
        listener.onDialClick("yes","1")
        var avp = image001.drawable as AnimatedVectorDrawable
        avp.start()
        activity?.runOnUiThread(300L) { // put however long your animation takes
            dismiss()
        }
    }
```